# Is there a better way to create a GUI in R?

Tags: r, user-interface

I am working on a program to analyze and process data for my lab, and I want to make it easier to use for others in my lab who are not as familiar with programming or the R workspace as I am.

Of course the first thing that comes to mind is a GUI, but all the answers and suggestions I have seen are around a decade old at this point and some packages like gWidgets2 do not quite work the same as their predecessors and the newer versions are severly lacking in accessable tutorials for someone like me who only has a mild ammount of experience in R, and no experience designing/working with GUIs.

I already have most of the actual programming done. I just need a GUI element that takes an integer input, and another element that takes a list of strings. Then I need both of those passed to R where it can complete its data arrangement according to what I have already written.

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/ may be a simpler approach

Comment: Shiny? It's oriented towards building web apps but can also be used to e.g. embed a GUI in an RMarkdown document

Comment: Nothing has much changed in this area. R is not a language that prioritized building GUIs.  Most people still use `shiny` for such interfaces when needed.

Comment: Have you tried jamovi, https://www.jamovi.org/? You can very easily program a module for your colleagues. See https://dev.jamovi.org/